# NSCoding custom object child array not persisting

Tags: ios, swift

I have two classes : Contact and Bill. Contact has an array of type Bill.

When I persist using NSKeyedArchiver my contacts persist just fine, however, it does not persist the Bill array.

Each time I add a a Bill or a Contact I call the `insertNewObject()` method in persist.

Here are my classes :

```
/* Persist.swift */
import Foundation

class Persist {

    static let sharedInstance = Persist()

    let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    var contactsFilePath : String {
        let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let url = manager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first! as NSURL
        return url.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(delegate.userId):objectsArrayz").path!
    }

    func insertNewObject(){
        NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(delegate.contacts!, toFile: contactsFilePath)

    }

    func retrieveContracts(){
        if let array = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(contactsFilePath) as? [Contact] {
            delegate.contacts = array
        }
    }

    func deleteContact(rowNum : Int){
        delegate.contacts!.removeAtIndex(rowNum)
        NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(delegate.contacts!, toFile: contactsFilePath)
    }

/* Contact.swift */    
import Foundation

class Contact : NSObject, NSCoding{

    var image : UIImage?
    var firstName : String?
    var lastName : String?
    var email : String?
    var phoneNumber : String?
    var address : String?
    var bills : [Bill]?

    init(image: UIImage, firstName : String, lastName : String, email : String, phoneNumber : String, address : String, bills : [Bill]) {
        self.image = image
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.email = email
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
        self.address = address
        self.bills = bills
    }

    // MARK: NSCoding

    required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        guard let image = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("image") as? UIImage,
            let firstName = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("firstName") as? String,
            let lastName = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("lastName") as? String,
            let email = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("email") as? String,
            let phoneNumber = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("phoneNumber") as? String,
            let address = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("address") as? String,
            let bills = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("bills") as? [Bill]
        else {
                return nil
        }

        self.init(
            image: image,
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName : lastName,
            email : email,
            phoneNumber : phoneNumber,
            address : address,
            bills : bills

        )
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encodeObject(self.image, forKey: "image")
        coder.encodeObject(self.firstName, forKey: "firstName")
        coder.encodeObject(self.lastName, forKey: "lastName")
        coder.encodeObject(self.email, forKey: "email")
        coder.encodeObject(self.phoneNumber, forKey: "phoneNumber")
        coder.encodeObject(self.address, forKey: "address")
        coder.encodeObject(self.bills, forKey: "bills")
    }
}


/* Bill.swift*/
import Foundation

class Bill : NSObject, NSCoding{

    var service : String?
    var subtotal : Double?
    var taxes : Double?
    var total : Double?


    init(service : String, subtotal : Double, taxes : Double, total: Double) {
        self.service = service
        self.subtotal = subtotal
        self.taxes = taxes

    }

    // MARK: NSCoding

    required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {

        guard let service = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("service") as? String,
            let subtotal = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("subtotal") as? Double,
            let taxes = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("taxes") as? Double,
            let total = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("total") as? Double

            else {
                return nil
        }


        self.init(
            service: service,
            subtotal: subtotal,
            taxes: taxes,
            total: total

        )
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encodeObject(self.service, forKey: "service")
        coder.encodeObject(self.subtotal, forKey: "subtotal")
        coder.encodeObject(self.taxes, forKey: "taxes")
        coder.encodeObject(self.total, forKey: "total")
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the same happen if you declare bills as non optional? i.e. `var bills : [Bill]!` Just be sure that there's a zero-length array there e.g. `var bills : [Bill]! = [Bill]()`

Comment: Yes I did change my variables to non-optionals, however it didn't help me out.

Comment: And what-if you use NSArray / NSMutableArrays explicitly rather than implied Arrays? e.g. declaring bills as an NSArray? Another way of doing this (As far as I know is) by: `var bills : [Bill] = []`. I could be wrong here.. But explicitly using: `var bills: NSArray` is a last resort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A call to super.init() is required in the serializable class's init method.

Snippet from Bill.swift

```
 required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init()
        service = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("service") as? String
        subtotal = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("subtotal") as? Double
        taxes = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("taxes") as? Double
        total = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("total") as? Double
        services = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("services") as? [Service]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a guide from the apple dev docs (in objective-c):

> Discussion You must return self from initWithCoder:. If you have an
>   advanced need that requires substituting a different object after
>   decoding, you can do so in awakeAfterUsingCoder:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    [super encodeWithCoder:coder];
    // Implementation continues
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _firstName = [coder decodeObjectForKey:ASCPersonFirstName];
        _lastName = [coder decodeObjectForKey:ASCPersonLastName];
        _height = [coder decodeFloatForKey:ASCPersonHeight];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: He is using the coder designated initialiser. Without it, he wouldn't be able to compile as it wouldn't confirm to the protocol. Secondly, the code is in swift, not Obj-C.